# Difference between R.layout and android.R.layout

Tags: android, layout, android-arrayadapter

What is the difference between

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sarray);
```

What is the difference between `R.layout` and `android.R.layout`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`R.layout.*` are layouts you provide (in res/layout, for example).

`android.R.layout.*` are layouts that ship with the Android SDK.

Comment: just to add, `R.layout` is actually shortcut for `your.package.R.layout`

Answer (score 5):

`R.layout` denotes the resources which are provided by your application. All the variables, resource files (drawable, string, layout etc) which are defined by your application can be accessed by R.

Example `R.layout.*, R.drawable.*, R.id.*, R.color.*`, etc

But `android.R` denotes the resources of your android SDK. all the resources which are not defines by you but are defined by android SDK will be available to you if you use `android.R`

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sarray);
```

here you have not defined an xml named `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`

`R.layout.main` denotes there an xml file whose name is main in your layout directory

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 2):

`R.layout.*` is provided in our application that is built by us whereas `android.R.*` is something that comes with Android SDK that means they are predefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.R.
```

is used for access predefined classes by android SDK (layouts/drawables)

```
R
```

is used for access custom classes(that means its layouts/drawables imported/created  by user)