# Firebase listView app crashes while populating Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-recyclerview, adapter

While populating ListView app crashes.

Error: null point Exception

```
public class Recycler extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListView mListView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://afirebaseproject-eab4d.firebaseio.com/data/a");

        FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
                this,
                String.class,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                ref
        )
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

               TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                text.setText(model);
            }
        };
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

XML
ListView id- list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    ....
    tools:context="shah.parth.temp2.Recycler">

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/list"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ListView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the error which I am getting

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: shah.parth.temp2, PID: 2845
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shah.parth.temp2/shah.parth.temp2.Recycler}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at shah.parth.temp2.Recycler.onCreate(Recycler.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: okay i did that. ps: Im new here

Answer (score 0):

For your FirebaseListAdapter, you're using **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** as your layout for each ListItem.

In the **populateView** method, you are looking for the view **android.R.id.list**.
The **populateView** method is the method where you assign the values in the views of your layout and here are the views in the layout, **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
   android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

If you look in the code, there is no view with an id of **list** but rather a view with an id of **text1**. With that, when the findViewById method will start to find the view with an ID of **list**, it would get nothing and when you **setText** to nothing, it would invoke a **NullPointerException**

To fix this, just change the id in your **populateView** method to **text1** so that it would get the appropriate view.

You should also change your code on line 12:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Using **android.R** would refer to resources that are built-in with the Android SDK and **R** would refer to resources your provide or create in your application.

See this post for more info: [Difference between R.layout and android.R.layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434970/difference-between-r-layout-and-android-r-layout)

Comment: id for ListView is list only

Comment: protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

                   ListView text = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                    text.text(model);
                }

Comment: For your List Adapter, you are using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 as your layout for the List Item and android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 has android.R.id.text1 as the container for the value. Your R.id.list would refer to your whole list, not to the container for the values which would be placed in the list

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
           TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to

```
         TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```